# How can I extend a linear regression line and predict the future?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I use package scipy.stats to generate a linear regression line as follow:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

value = np.array([51, 54, 66, 58, 25, 78, 69, 35, 95]) 
year = np.array([2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]) 

y = pd.Series(value) 
x = pd.Series(year)

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)

line = [slope*xi + intercept for xi in x]

plt.plot(x, line, color = 'orange', label="Fitting Line", linewidth=1)
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 5, marker = '.', label="Sample Point", color = 'dodgerblue')
plt.show()
```

From the current stage, the regression line only covers the existing potions, but I wish to predict the value of ten years later. Is there any other efficient way to directly visualize the prediction line on the chart(Actually extend the line)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a new set of x-values for predictions

```
years_extended = np.arange(2010, 2028, 1)

y = pd.Series(value) 
x = pd.Series(year)

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)

line = [slope*xi + intercept for xi in years_extended]

plt.plot(years_extended, line, color = 'orange', label="Fitting Line", linewidth=1)
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 5, marker = '.', label="Sample Point", color = 'dodgerblue')
plt.xticks(range(2010, 2029, 2))
```

[image]