# How can I implement Monte Carlo simulation to add extra data points following a specific curve trend of 5 experimental data points?

Tags: python, simulation, curve-fitting, montecarlo, data-generation

I have an exponential curve and 5 external experimental data points, and I need to create a Monte Carlo simulation which will be adding extra data points following the same trend of the existing 5 data points (in relation to their deviation from the curve). My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def probability(dose):
    p = 1 - np.exp(- b0 - b1*dose)
    return p


b0 = 0.0097
b1 = 0.0449
d = np.linspace(0, 3.5, 1000)[1:]

x = d
y = probability(d)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim(xmin=0)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.yticks([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1])
a = [0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 2]
b = [0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.05, 0.09]
plt.scatter(a, b, cmap='hot', clip_on=False)
plt.title("Dose-Response for acrylamide")
plt.xlabel("Dose")
plt.ylabel("Probability")
plt.show()
```

Since I know very little of coding Monte Carlo simulation with Python, any help would be appreciated a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look at using linear regression for prediction, such as at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205263/how-can-i-extend-a-linear-regression-line-and-predict-the-future. Sorry, not quite an answer to your question.

Comment: That may not qualify exactly as Monte Carlo simulation but it's good enough for plan B, so thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome! People on here have helped me out hugely sometimes.  Monte Carlo is used a lot to test out something that's basically already known, by iterating a zillion times with different choices, like with coin flips. You get sort of a bell curve centered on the most probable outcome, but you can still get 5 heads in a row.  I don't see how it could work for you in your example.